# How to sort R Shiny datatable containing null values?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

For instance, consider the following minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
    ui = bootstrapPage(dataTableOutput("myTable")),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$myTable <- renderDataTable(
            # Use format() because want output to fixed number of decimal places
            data.frame(x = sample(c(format(seq(-10, 10, 2), nsmall = 2), rep("", 3))))
        )
    }
))
```

The corresponding output in a browser is (when sorted):

[image]

which is clearly not right (-8.0 is being ordered between 0.0 and -6.0, for instance).

This is most likely due to the presence of nulls causing the entire column to be sorted as a string type, rather than numeric.

Is there any way round this?

### Edit

Note also that I also require the output to a fixed number of decimal places, which makes things trickier.

Also, I'd like null values to always be sorted to the bottom of the table.

Comment: I think you are correct on the column becoming a character vector. How do you want the empty values sorted - beginning? end? omitted?

Comment: @JohnPaul - always at end would be good, thanks.

Comment: The `format` is what converts the numeric to string.